# ERROR @wdio/cli:launcher: No specs found to run, exiting with failure

Tags: docker, webdriver-io, aws-codepipeline

I have been trying to integrate my wdio framework with AWS codepipeline.

The Test seems to work fine locally , but when i try to trigger using the codepipeline, I get the below error

```
ERROR @wdio/cli:launcher: No specs found to run, exiting with failure
ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: Error in onCompleteHook: Error: There were issues reading JSON-files from '.tmp/json'.
```

This errror occurs while i have updated my node to v17.3.1 (Earlier version 14). Can anyone help me identify the issue here

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.5.1",
  "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
  "@wdio/cli": "^7.20.9",
  "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.20.8",
  "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.20.9",
  "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.20.8",
  "@wdio/shared-store-service": "^7.20.2",
  "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.20.0",
  "chai": "^4.3.6",
  "chromedriver": "^104.0.0",
},
"dependencies": {
  "@wdio/types": "^7.20.7",
  "node-typescript-compiler": "^3.0.0",
  "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
  "tsc": "^2.0.4",
  "tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.0",
  "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2"
}
```

Docker file

```
    FROM ianwalter/puppeteer:latest
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY * /app/
    
    RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
    RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | apt-key add -
    RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable main"
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install microsoft-edge-stable
    
    
    RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    RUN apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    
    RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A6DCF7707EBC211F
    RUN apt-add-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic main"
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends firefox
    
    RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-11-jre-headless
    RUN npm ci
    RUN npx selenium-standalone install
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        software-properties-common \
        npm
    RUN npm install n -g && \
        n latest
    RUN npm -v
    RUN node -v



ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "Test"]
CMD ["--tag=@PipelineTest --browserName=chrome"]
```

buildspec

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    TAGS: "@Full"
    BROWSER: "chrome"

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - docker login 
      - docker build
      - docker push
      
  build:
    commands: 
      - docker pull
      - docker run 
   

reports:
  automation-cucumber-report:
    files:
      - reports/*
      - reports/**/*
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of files rather than posting screenshots. The search engines cannot index the screenshot, and SO users cannot paste the contents into their own environment to try to help you by reproducing the issue.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by down version node to Version 16 and "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.2.0".